# Buttons inside StackPanel

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, orientation, stackpanel

I have stack panel (1 row x 6 column) contains 6 buttons:

```
 <StackPanel Background="AntiqueWhite" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="a1" Content="a1" />
            <Button x:Name="a2" Content="a2" />
            <Button x:Name="a3" Content="a3" />
            <Button x:Name="a4" Content="a4" />
            <Button x:Name="a5" Content="a5" />
            <Button x:Name="a6" Content="a6" />
        </StackPanel>
```

Now they looks like below:

[image]

How to set up, that one button will be into one column ?

Update: Grid Def:

```
<Grid Background="AliceBlue">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is. Do you want the buttons to appear on top of eachother? As a single column? If so you can set the StackPanel's `Orientation` to `Vertical`.

Comment: for example I have 10 columns, I created stack panel and inside one button should be into one column......or maybe remove stackpanel?

Comment: "maybe remove stackpanel". That's it. Put the Buttons directly into the Grid and assign appropriate `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` values.

Comment: `StackPanel` will assign the least amount of space possible for items inside while `Grid` will assign maximum available space, however if you put `Grid` inside of the `StackPanel` then `Grid` gets only what `StackPanel` gives.

Comment: thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it like this :

```
<Grid Background="AliceBlue">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> //width will be divided equally among 6 columns
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            //Row definations will go here
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Content="a1" Grid.Column="0" />
        <Button Content="a2" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Button Content="a1" Grid.Column="2" />
        <Button Content="a2" Grid.Column="3" />
        <Button Content="a1" Grid.Column="4" />
        <Button Content="a2" Grid.Column="5" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Good. Then may be you can share your answer or accept the one from mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to allow each buttons to one column like

```
<Button x:Name="a1" Content="a1" Grid.Column="0" />
<Button x:Name="a2" Content="a2" Grid.Column="1" />
```

So for that define a grid inside your Stackpanel like:

```
<StackPanel>
<Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        ....
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
<Buttons Grid.Column="..."/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Can you provide your grid definition ?